# ¿Cómo aplicar una expresión regular a más de una columna en una misma línea de comandos?

Tags: linux, regex, awk, sed, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un fichero csv y me gustaría extraer aquellos datos que:

- de una columna que contienen el mes de octubre, que aparece como "/10/"
- también aquellos datos de otra columna que empiezan por "08".

Hasta ahora solo consigo sacar los datos de octubre mediante:

```
cat fichero.csv | cut -d "," -f2,3 | grep /10/
```

Lo que no consigo es unir ahora en la misma línea de comandos otra expresión regular que indique aquellos datos de la segunda columna que empiezan por 08.

Sé que la expresión regular para extraer datos que comiencen con un patrón determinado podría ser `grep ^08`, pero no sé cómo concatenarla al grep utilizado anteriormente.

Añado una parte de la salida que obtengo hasta ahora:

```
$ cat datosCovid.csv | cut -d "," -f2,3 | grep /10/

01/10/2020,8040138
01/10/2020,43007051
02/10/2020,8000271
02/10/2020,8000347
01/10/2020,8000384
01/10/2020,8000499
02/10/2020,8000578
02/10/2020,8000918
02/10/2020,8001029
02/10/2020,8001030
01/10/2020,8001133
01/10/2020,8001157
02/10/2020,8001297
01/10/2020,8001731
01/10/2020,8001777
01/10/2020,8001807
01/10/2020,8001923
02/10/2020,8002071
01/10/2020,8002186
01/10/2020,8002198
01/10/2020,8002216
01/10/2020,8002368
01/10/2020,8002587
02/10/2020,8002666
02/10/2020,8003695
02/10/2020,8003816
01/10/2020,8003907
01/10/2020,8004031
01/10/2020,8004225
01/10/2020,8004717
01/10/2020,8004869
```

Es un fichero con muchos datos así que muestro solo algunos. Como se puede ver, el mes de octubre lo tengo localizado. Ahora me gustaría localizar aquellos códigos que están después de la fecha que empiecen por 08.

Comment: por favor muestra un ejemplo de fichero, así como cómo quieres que sea la salida

Comment: añado captura de pantalla de la salida que tengo por ahora.

Comment: no no, texto para que se pueda reproducir fácilmente. También importante ver cómo querrías que fuera la salida. ¿Hay algún otro tipo de impedimentos? Porque en anteriores preguntas tuyas hablabas de la imposibilidad de usar awk o sed

Comment: ah vale perdón. La vuelvo a editar entonces. Para este caso puedo utilizar awk y sed ya que es el módulo dónde los estoy empezando a ver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que tienes un fichero con campos separados por comas. Un CSV, vaya.

Quieres mostrar la 2.ª y 3.ª columna de las líneas en que:

- En la 2.ª columna aparezca "/10/"
- La 3.ª columna empiece por "08"

Todo ello podemos decírselo a Awk así:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$2 ~ /\/10\// && $3 ~ /^08/ {print $2,$3}' fichero
```

Es decir:

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` define cuál es el separador de campos (FS) y cuál usamos para la salida (en print, OFS)
- `condiciones {print $2,$3}` si se cumplen las condiciones, imprime 2.ª y 3.ª columna
- donde las condiciones son `$2 ~ /\/10\// && $3 ~ /^08/` que vienen a comprobar expresiones regulares: que el 2.º campo contenga /10/ y que el 3.º empiece por 08.

---

Tal y como explico en los comentarios, la versión Awk es potente y útil, pero tal vez algo enrevesada si está empezando con el procesamiento de textos. Por eso, recomiendo también una versión consistente en usar "grep" dos veces seguidas:

```
grep -E "^\d{1,2}/10/" | grep ",08"
```

La primera extrae las líneas que son de la forma "NN/10/", es decir, aquellas en la que la columna tiene /10/ después de uno o dos números.
La segunda extrae, de entre esas líneas, las que tienen "08" al principio.

Comment: Vaya, al final resultó ser más complicado de lo que pensé. Creía que con un grep me sería posible! Tendré que ver cómo funciona ```awk``` por si necesito volver a utilizarlo más tarde. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodríguezPardo la respuesta que puse es... no sé, como "para nota". Si quieres usar Grep, puedes hacerlo por ejemplo así: `cosas | ... | cut -d"," -f2,3 | grep -E "^\d{1,2}/10/" | grep ",08`. Fíjate que en `grep -E "^\d{1,2}/10/"` valido que haya un "/10/" en el primer campo, espacio para el mes. En `grep ",08"` valido que haya el texto "08" después de la coma; es decir, que esté al principio del segundo campo.

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta explicándolo con más extensión.

Comment: fredorqui una pregunta, realizando esa expresión no obtengo ningun output. Esto haciendolo siguiente: ```cat datosCovid.csv | cut -d"," -f2,3 | grep -E "^\d{1,2}/10/" | grep ",08"``` ¿Estaría bien lo que he heho, no? Es queno sé por qué no obtengo ninguna salida.

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodríguezPardo dependerá del Grep que tengas. Lo mismo no le gusta `\d` para los numéricos y puedes probar con `grep -E "^[0-9]{1,2}/10/"`.

Comment: No depende de la versión de grep (salvo que uses BSD grep en lugar de GNU grep). `-E` usa regexes POSIX, por lo tanto `\d` no está soportado. Puedes usar `[[:digit:]]` en su lugar, o `[0-9]`. Otra opción es ejecutar grep en modo regex tipo PCRE con el parámetro `-P` en lugar de `-E`, así permitirás `\d` entre otros

Comment: Pues debía de ser eso! Mediante ```cat datosCovid.csv | cut -d"," -f2,3 | grep -E "^[0-9]{1,2}/10/" | grep ",08"``` sí que me generó el ouput deseado. Gracias fedorqui y Julio!!

Answer (score 2):

Y qué tal encadenando un segundo grep?

Sería básicamente ampliar el comando que ya habías preparado:

```
cat datosCovid.csv | cut -d "," -f2,3 | grep /10/ | grep ,08
```

Como previamente solo has sacado dos columnas, solo existirá una coma, y por lo tanto puedes filtrar por ",08".

El peligro a veces de filtrar por expresiones tan sencillas como ",08" es que puedas encontrar ese mismo patrón en otro sitio (por ejemplo, si tuvieras varias columnas), pero en este caso no debería haber problema porque solo existe una coma.

Comment: esto fallaría con líneas que tengan "/10/" en otros lugares, mira mi respuesta para cómo puede resolverse de forma más segura.

Comment: Gracias! También me sirvió! Antes estaba intentando hacer algo similar pero me faltaba poner la coma delante del 08, es decir, estaba haciendo ```cat datosCovid.csv | cut -d "," -f2,3 | grep /10/ | grep 08``` y por eso buscaba otros patrones diferentes a los que quería. Saludos!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', con el ejemplo que OP puso, es imposible encontrar "/10/" en otros lugares

Comment: Cierto, en este caso solo puede haber /10/ en esta posición.